# Steam Inventory PHP

Tags: php, steam, steam-web-api, steambot

how is it possible the number of a particular item to read?
For example: How many items are available from this id?: 927007517

Code:

```
<?php

    $content = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198131798299/inventory/json/730/2');
    $result = json_decode($content);
    if($result->success !== true) {
        echo 'Nicht erfolgreich! :(';
        return;
    }

    foreach($result->rgInventory AS $item) {
        echo $item->classid.'<br />';
    }

?>
```

Output: http://csgo.square7.ch/csgo-master/api.php

Thank You.
With best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can count how many times a value returns using the [`array_count_values`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) function. This will create a new array with the id's as keys and the count as value.

Like so:

```
$count = array_count_values($result->rgInventory);
echo $count['927007517'] // Will echo the number of times this id is found
```

Comment: OP wants classID not array index

Answer (score 0):

You can't use array_count_values but you can write simple counter

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198131798299/inventory/json/730/2');
$result = json_decode($content);
if($result->success !== true) {
    echo 'Nicht erfolgreich! :(';
    return;
}
$count = [];

foreach($result->rgInventory as $item) {
    array_key_exists($item->classid, $count) ? ++$count[$item->classid] : ($count[$item->classid] = 0);
}

echo $count[927007517];
```